# Mac app package. Is this normal?

Tags: xcode, macos

I have build and sent my app to apple store (mac apple store)

But when I go to organizer and when I try to share > and save it as package it's ok
but when I run the package I get a error message, "this pachage can't be installed"
if I share it as .app file it works okay. Is that normal?
I sent the file to apple via xcode
what will they receive .app file or pkg?

Answer (score 0):

It is normal. These packages aren't meant to be distributed to users but only to test the App Store purchase and installation process, see the [Tools Workflow Guide for Mac](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/OSXWorkflowGuide/DistributingApplications/DistributingApplications.html):

> "Before you submit to the Mac App Store, you should test the 
>   installation process to verify that your app installs correctly. You
>   can do this by saving the installer package to your disk and running a
>   test using the installer command before submitting it."

Users who purchase/load your apps via the App Store will be able to install it. You can test this on the package you've created and saved locally with:

```
sudo installer -store -pkg path-to-package -target /
```

If you want to create a package to be distributed to users, use the PackageMaker that is part of Xcode (it's included in the Auxiliary Tools).